# How to force Awesome to show actual xterm title even when it is hidden?

Tags: taskbar, xterm, awesome-wm

When I hide an xterm apparently the Awesome WM transforms the title to simply *"xterm"* instead of showing the actual window's name.

For example if I have this (querying with `xwininfo`):

```
 xwininfo: Window id: 0x5c0000d "xterm:john:$   top"
 Map State: IsViewable
 ...
```

But then if I click on the taskbar to "hide" this xterm, `xwininfo` says this:

```
 xwininfo: Window id: 0x5c0000d "xterm:john:$   top"
 Map State: isUnmapped
 ...
```

So my xterm which is not viewable anymore is seen, by xwininfo, as "isUnmapped" (as opposed to isViewable).  But its title didn't change: it is still `"xterm:john:$   top"`.

So far so good. Except that Awesome is now displaying, in the taskbar, only "xterm" instead of the actual xterm's title.

So I have the behavior I want when the xterm is visible, but I don't have the behavior I want when the xterm is hidden.

How can I get Awesome to display the actual xterm's title instead of simply "xterm" in both cases?

Bonus point if I can get Awesome to show `"[HIDDEN]: xterm:john:$   top"`, so I know immediately if the xterm is currently viewable or not.

P.S: I've got a pretty custom xterm title, updating at each command, indicating whether a command is currently running or not etc. and as far as I know my customization always set the xterm's window title correctly (as can be seen by xwininfo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably displaying the icon title.  You can see that information using `xprop`, e.g., as the `WM_ICON_NAME` and `_NET_WM_ICON_NAME` properties.  `xwininfo` shows only information for the selected *window* (an icon is actually a different window).

The escape sequence used to set the title string has a [**`2`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-2.FB9) parameter, to denote just the window title.  Changing that to [**`0`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-0.FB7) tells xterm to set both icon and window titles.

Comment: tyvm, I was indeed passing "2" in my escape sequence. I had no idea about the icon/title difference!  I got the behavior I wanted by changing to "0".